# Drawing on p5.js canvas while canvas is rotating

Tags: canvas, p5.js

I'm working on simulating a drawing machine using p5.js, similar to [this](https://www.instagram.com/p/Btlqs7_nZUN/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link).

I have already created the positioning of the arm relative to the motor positions. The idea I'm trying to recreate is holding a pencil/pen still and using it to draw on a rotating canvas underneath. I have a test [example](https://editor.p5js.org/dwarren/sketches/Ggwfab9Sn) created in the p5.js editor.

The [example](https://editor.p5js.org/dwarren/sketches/Ggwfab9Sn) draws two dots, one red and one blue. The goal is to create a mark, or trail, using the blue dot on the rotating graphics object below.

```js
    function setup() {
        createCanvas(400, 400);
        background(255);
        img = createGraphics(200, 200);
        img.background(150);
        img.strokeWeight(3);
        //rectMode(CENTER);
      }

      function draw() {
        background('lightYellow');
        translate(100, 100);
        img.background('lightBlue');
        img.push();
          img.translate(100, 100);
          img.rotate(radians(frameCount));
          img.fill(240);
          img.noStroke();
          img.rect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
          img.strokeWeight(4);
          img.stroke('red');
          img.point(20, 20);
        img.pop();

        img.stroke('blue');
        img.strokeWeight(4);
        img.point(100, 80);
        image(img, 0, 0);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to do this with my current example or should I try something different?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you're asking. What does this code do differently from what you expected it to do?

Comment: See the answer from Julian. It does exactly what I was wanting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of achieving what you want to do with your example sketch would be to rotate both the graphics object and the sketch at the same rate. I rewrote some of your code to achieve the goal, but it shouldn't be too different to follow:

```js
let rotatingRect;

function setup(){
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  
  rotatingRect = createGraphics(100, 100);
  rotatingRect.background(240);
  rotatingRect.strokeWeight(4);
  rotatingRect.stroke('red');
  rotatingRect.point(20, 20);
}

function draw(){
  
  noStroke();
  background('lightyellow');
  fill('lightblue');
  rect(100, 100, 200, 200);
  
  rotatingRect.stroke('blue');
  
  push();
    translate(200, 200);
    rotate(radians(frameCount));
    
    rotatingRect.push();
      rotatingRect.translate(50, 50);
      rotatingRect.rotate(-radians(frameCount));
      rotatingRect.point(mouseX-200, mouseY-200);
      //rotatingRect.point(0, -10);
    rotatingRect.pop();
  
    image(rotatingRect, -50, -50);
  pop();
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

One thing that's different is that the blue dot's position is determined by the mouse. You can change this behavior by commenting the `rotatingRect.point(mouseX-200, mouseY-200);` line and using `rotatingRect.point(0, -10);` instead. It's worth to note that [points](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/point) are being drawn and, depending on the speed of the rotation or of the blue dot(if it's movable), the trail won't be continuous. To achieve that, I would start to keep track of the previous positions of the blue dot and use something like [line()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/line) instead of `point()` between the last position and the current one.

Comment: This is a great example, thank you!
I hadn't thought about rotating the entire canvas, and rotating the rectangle the opposite amount. This is how I was achieving the effect of moving the paper "up" as it was drawing, and it transfers easily to rotation as well.

Comment: Nice. Hope it was helpful.